# How to read "(x+y)^z" in Japanese?

Tags: mathematics

How to read "(x+y)^z" in Japanese?

Is this correct?

かっこ ｘ たす ｙ かっこーとじ の ｚ じ

Kakko x tasu y kakko-toji no z jo

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56962/5010

Comment: Um, your TL is describing an entirely different equation... how did you get to that...?

Comment: 2乗(にじょ**う**) is "square" (`^2`), not exponentiation in general (`^n`).

Comment: @naruto yes, z is an exponent.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Thank you for pointing that. I'm sorry for the mistake. I mistakenly copied the other translation from my document. I edited the question now.

Comment: ひく is "minus". Did you want to say たす "plus"? And note that じ, じょ and じょう are totally different sounds in Japanese. Don't omit the (ょ)う.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please read this first: [Standard mathematical operations, expressed in Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56962/5010)

As described in the question above, there are several approaches to read this. The most simple approach is to read each symbol one by one. This `^` symbol can be read ハット, キャレット or 累乗【るいじょう】.

> かっこ エックス たす ワイ かっことじ るいじょう ゼット

More naturally, the expression x<sup>n</sup> can be read as "xのn乗" (エックス の エヌ じょう; "x to the power of n-th"). With this, you can read it like this:

> かっこ エックス たす ワイ かっことじ の ゼット じょう

If you omit かっこ/かっことじ and say it like this:

> エックス たす ワイ の ゼット じょう

...it may be taken as x + y<sup>z</sup> rather than (x + y)<sup>z</sup>. This may be okay if everyone is actually seeing the expression on a screen or a blackboard.

You can avoid this ambiguity by using 和【わ】:

> エックス と ワイ の わ の ゼット じょう
>   (literally, "x-and-y's sum, to the z-th power")

Note that にじょう is "to the second" or "square" (x<sup>2</sup>), not n-th power in general (x<sup>n</sup>).