# Pronouncing while loops in programming

Tags: word-choice, computing

I am wondering how Japanese developers read aloud a piece of computer code to other developers. Take the following C/C++ code for example

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
    foo(i);
    i++;
}
```

What is the natural way to read out this code? This is my attempt

```
iは0。
i小なり10だったら
  iを引数としてfooを呼び出す
  iをインクリメントする
繰り返し
```

Does it sound fine? Also, there is a possibly that the 繰り返し part might be ambiguous since it might refer to the previous line or the second line. How to fix that part?

---

Bonus: How to pronounce the above piece of code using お嬢様言葉? For a bit of context, I read this [amusing article](https://forest.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/serial/yajiuma/1419370.html) about using Japanese in C++ and I am thinking about creating a compiler for that weird programming language.

```
iは0ですわ。
もしi<10でしたら
  iを差し上げましてfooを実行させて頂きますのですわ
  iをインクリメントするのですわ
繰り返し
```

How does that sound? How to make it sound more お嬢様らしい?

Comment: Kind of relevant https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E8%A8%80%E8%AA%9E

Comment: First thing a Japanese C dev would say: "え、なんでforループじゃないの？".

Comment: @dungarian 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not common practice to "translate" such codes into Japanese, at least not among professionals. They just read this mostly in (katakanized) English, token by token. Typically something like this:

```
イント アイ イコール ゼロ
ワイル アイ しょうなり じゅう (かっこ)
フー アイ
アイ プラスプラス
(かっことじ)
```

Few English-speaking developers read this code like "Declare an integer variable i and assign zero to it" or "Call f with i as an argument" while doing a professional code review, either.

かっこ and かっことじ are used when you really need to read parentheses out loud, but they can be usually omitted. If you really need to distinguish, しょうかっこ refers to `(`/`)`, ちゅうかっこ refers to `{`/`}`. セミコロン (`;`) is usually omitted for the same reason, too.

お嬢様コーディング is an extension of 日本語プログラミング言語, which is a fairly rare attempt and is considered useless by most developers. No one wants to type iをインクリメントする instead of `i++`, so it is nothing more than a joke. (As a joke, I love 以上ですの at the end of a loop, though.)

Related: [Standard mathematical operations, expressed in Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56962/5010)